# How to use Maven to make a Java EE 6 project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven

I have used Eclipse to make a `EJB project`, `Dynamic Web project` and then I have combined these to in a `EAR project`. Now I am learning Maven and I wonder how you manage how you do this?

If I use an archetype that generates a javaee6-webapp then after what I understand you get a WAR archive....but that can only use the subset of the JavaEE6 specifiaction. I want to use the whole. So do I need to use one archetype for javaee6-ejb and one for javaee6-webapp, and then combine these in some way?

If this is the case or there are other better approaces I would be happy to learn about it.

Or are the EJBs in a webapp project generated by an archetype compiled and packed as a library and added to the WEB-INF/lib folder? If so, does it have access to the full JavaEE6 API if deployed in a full profile app server?

Answer (score 4):

[This article](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/is_java_ee_6_war) by Adam Bien might be interesting for you.

Also, if I understand it correctly, you **can use** all the goods of Java EE 6 specification using WAR deployment. You can use timers, remote interfaces, asynchronous invocation etc. in your WAR.
It just depends if you use Full vs Web Profile.

There are few differences between EAR and WAR packaging but, in my opinion, the biggest added value of EAR is the separation of concerns and modules (business logic from web).

Comment: Ah, so WAR doesn't limit you to web profile only? However, would it be better to make seperate projects like in eclipse?

Comment: You should test it, but I'm 95% sure that WAR vs EAR is only about differences in packaging, classloaders, JNDI, etc. and not about the Full vs Web profile. And sure - modules (or Eclipse Projects) separation is always nice :-)

Comment: This article is misleading, if you put an ejb.jar in web-inf lib, sure the classes will be available but your server (in general) does NOT know to deploy the ejbs, to get them to deploy this way he'll have some special server configuration

Comment: @jermel so, you're saying that i.e. `@Stateless` and `@Stateful` annotated POJOS wrapped into *.jar and put into WEB-INF/lib will not be recognized by the app server? Or perhaps you are referring to the `ejb-jar.xml` discovery?

Comment: @Piotr I'm referring to the ejb-jar.xml discovery.

Comment: Of course, but I think that's why Adam used `(EJB)-JARs` where EJB is in parentheses. It is a JAR with EJB's but it's not a standalone EJB-JAR module. As section 20.4 from EJB 3.1 spec says *"A .jar file in WEB-INF/lib that contains enterprise beans is **not** considered an independent Java EE "module" in the way that a .war file, stand-alone ejb-jar file, or an .ear-level ejb-jar file is considered a module. **Such a .jar does not define its own module name or its own namespace for ejb-names, environment dependencies, persistence units, etc.**"*

Comment: Yep as long as he doesn't think he as singleton ejbs deployed he's ok, if he shares the ejb.jar in 2 different WARs he may have unintended behavior.

Comment: Are you referring to the situation in which the Singleton EJB (which resides in two different WARs) is not a Singleton any more (there are two instances of this EJB)? Isn't this the same situation in case of two EARs?

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea.

Create all of your maven projects such as ejb-javaee6, webapp-javaee6, etc.
Then IF you want, create an maven [ear-javaee6](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/index.html) project to bundle them all together.  This EAR would reference your ejb and webapp.

**Updated link:**
Eclipse has a [plugin for maven](http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse) that makes your life easier

Comment: your link 'pluging for maven' requires login.

Answer (score 1):

To start quickly you can also use a maven archetype like this http://seam-archetype.sourceforge.net/jbosscc-seam-archetype/1.4/javaee.html